# How to setup a SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable?

Tags: java, shell, sudo

What does setting up a SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable mean? How do you do it? Where do I declare it?

I am trying to use a shell script to shutoff my computer after a couple of minutes and initiate this script with java.

Answer (score 18):

So I am not sure I'd use `$SUDO_ASKPASS` for this. Basically the value of `$SUDO_ASKPASS` is to be an executable that will spit your password to standard out when invoked. So, if your password was 'foo', you could write a shell script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'foo'
```

and place it in `~/bin/pw.sh`. Then you would set the environment variable and execute the command as so:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/bin/pw.sh sudo shutdown -h now
```

that example assumes that you're on Darwin; `shutdown` behaves differently on different operating systems.

A more intelligent way of doing this (and more secure) is to use the `NOPASSWD` argument in `/etc/sudoers`. We would add a line like this:

```
jane ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

This again assumes you're on a Mac. And that your name is Jane. Change that. This way sudo will not ask for a password when you issue the command `/sbin/shutdown`. The command to (properly) [edit sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/visudo.man.html) is `visudo`.

Answer (score 4):

**Mac-specific answer:**

If you don't want your clear-text password in some file you can also invoke a GUI prompt to enter the password manually whenever something like `sudo -A ...` is called. To do so create a binary with the following content (taken from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23514)):

```
#!/bin/bash    
pw="$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)" && echo "$pw"
```

You can put it for example in a file called `~/bin/pw.sh`. Then make it executable by executing `chmod +x ~/bin/pw.sh`.

Finally set the environment variable to point to this file. Therefore put the following into `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` if you use Z shell):

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/bin/pw.sh
```

Finally test everything by executing `source ~/.bashrc` (or `source ~/.zshrc`) and then `sudo -A ls`.